# C++ Uploading file to ftp

Tags: c++, ftp

I am new to coding and I'm having trouble uploading a text file named "*test.txt*" to a ftp server.

Here is my code:

```
void nointernet()
{
std::cout << "No internet connection." << std::endl;
}

int upload()
{
HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (!hInternet)
{
    nointernet(); 
}


HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "FTPHOST", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "FTPUSER", "FTPPASS", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
if (!hFtpSession)
{
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    nointernet(); 

}

FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "D:/test.txt", "test.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0); 
std::cout << "File Uploaded." << std::endl;
InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession); 
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); 
return 0;
}

int main() {
upload();
return 0;
}
```

Any feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Error message, crash? We can't do anything without any additional information.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it. Here is the code if someone is interested:

```
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")

int upload()
{
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "HOST", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "USER", "PASS", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "C:/test.txt", "/test.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    std::cout << "File Uploaded." << std::endl;
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    upload();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would also use the INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE flag. According to Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770(v=vs.85).aspx ) unless the FTP is hosted on a Microsoft server, this flag is required